# Service dies when Nmap is run

Tags: networking, nmap

I am having a weird problem.
I have a service running on port 8888 on one of my many servers in a cluster.

When I run **nmap** on my gateway to get all the IPs inside my network, this service miraculously dies. Since nmap does a port scan too, It might have something to do with it. I am not sure.
The nmap command I am using is this:

```
sudo nmap -oX ${FILE_NAME} ${IP_DOMAIN} -A -O --osscan-guess
```

Can some tell me what might be happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Nmap developers try to limit the danger, [Nmap scans can still crash services](https://nmap.org/book/legal-issues.html#legal-crash). The most likely culprit for crashing a service (as opposed to crashing an entire machine) is the service version detection scan phase (`-sV`, implied in your command by `-A`). This scan sends a series of data packets to the service in an attempt to elicit a response which can be matched against Nmap's database of known services. When a match is found, Nmap stops sending probes. That means that an unknown service can get *lots* of probes sent to it which contain binary data, command strings, and other data that your service is not expecting.

A well-written network service will not crash on any input; your service has a bug of some sort. Avoiding this sort of crash usually means avoiding scanning that service:

- You can use [the `Exclude` directive](https://nmap.org/book/vscan-fileformat.html#vscan-db-exclude) in your `nmap-service-probes` data file to instruct Nmap to never send these service probes to port 8888.
- You can avoid scanning port 8888 at all by changing the ports you scan with `-p`. Later versions of Nmap will support the `--exclude-ports` option, too.
- You can make sure you are using the latest version of Nmap. If your service's fingerprint was added to the `nmap-service-probes` file, then Nmap will stop sending probes when it detects it, which may avoid sending the later probe that crashes it.
- You can reduce the intensity of the service scan with the [`--version-intensity`](https://nmap.org/book/man-version-detection.html#idm214689709712) option. This prevents Nmap from sending so many service probes, which may eliminate the one that is crashing your service.

Finally, if this service is a standard one and not something custom to your own network, you can report it to [The Network Scanning Watch List](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mXOacBSlncl6Y_gdi13eTMfCkRHf5u30TPZFV98yQHI/edit) so that other users can avoid crashing it as well.